# Vue CLI 3 creating lots of '*.hot-update.js' files. How to prevent that?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

For development purposes i don't use `npm run serve` because i'm integrating Vue with my backend project. Instead, i wrote my own command in package.json:

`"dev": "vue-cli-service build --mode development --watch"`

And it all works great, but it generates tons of webpack's hot-update.js files in my build dist directory and the problem is that they **don't** get deleted.

Is there a way to configure vue-cli/webpack in such way that these files are automatically deleted or not even created in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the development mode will automatically enable hot reloading when the watch flag is enabled.  Even though without the watch flag the development mode flag on build will not include hot reloading.  Confusing. I had to add this to my vue.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack(config) {
    config.plugins.delete("hmr")
  },
};
```

Note: that will ruin 
`npm run serve`